# R | How to create a column with values from previous period by ID

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks like this:

| period | id | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 |
| 1 | 2345 | 2 |
| 1 | 4567345 | 1 |
| 2 | 1234 | 3 |
| 2 | 2345 | 3 |
| 2 | 4567345 | 1 |
| 3 | 123467 | 2 |
| 3 | 234567 | 2 |
| 3 | 45673 | 1 |

I need to create a new column "category_pre" containing category values from previous period for each ID. If an ID is not found in previous period, the script should return "NA". The new column should be added to existing dataframe.

What would be the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `lag()` function here from `dplyr`:

```r
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(category_pre = lag(category, order_by=period))
df

  period      id category category_pre
   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1    1234        1           NA
2      1    2345        2           NA
3      1 4567345        1           NA
4      2    1234        3            1
5      2    2345        3            2
6      2 4567345        1            1
7      3  123467        2           NA
8      3  234567        2           NA
9      3   45673        1           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Step one, make a new data frame with period + 1:

```
df2 = data.frame(period=df$period+1, id=df$id, category=df$category)
```

Step two, merge the two data frames on period and id, `all.x=T` ensures that rows where there is no previous period are included (with NA):

```
merge(df, df2, by=c('period','id'), all.x = T)
```

Step three, rename the columns to category and category_pre.